# Discretizing continuous variables for RandomForest in Sklearn

Tags: python, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

I want to use Random Forest for feature selection based on Gini index. My dataset has mix of numeric (contiuous) and categorical(String) data. This is an example of the dataset

Var1            Var2
198             zcROj17IEC
336             DHeTmBftjz
252.3           crIgUHSK8h
252             ZSNrjIX0Db

I know trees works on discrete data (categorical) but does RandomForest in Sklearn require continuous numeric data to be discretized first or it can handle it?? For categorical string variables I used the following to encode the strings into numeric columns with zeros and ones

```
pandas.get_dummies(X['Var2'])
```

and it works but for the numeric I tried the following to discretize

```
pandas.qcut(X['Var1'], 2 , retbins=True)
```

but I keep getting an error of non-unique bins!

Do I need to discretize? How can I do it?

Comment: data example is not clear how can I post a table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random forest should support continuous variables no problem. See for example [this sample](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py).

Comment: that means also decision trees support continuous variables?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is in fact better to not categorise them - the tree can then optimally choose where to 'cut' the distribution. E.g. suppose the right decision cut is whether a feature is less or more than 15. If you discretise prior to that into bins [0, 10), [10, 20), [20, 30) etc. you will lose that information.

Answer (score 0):

Trees and Forest work worse when you make dummies from you categorical values.

You need just label you categorical features - that's all!